# I need help in javascript replace regex

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have a problem to do a replace in javascript with regex

this is the code

```
var link = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
var i = link.length;
   while(i--){
      var lnk = link[i].href;
       lnk.replace('/^http\:\/\/www\.ringtonematcher\.com\/go\/\?sid\=([\w]+)\&/g', 'test');
    }
```

sid=replace&   = sid=test&

Comment: Could you tell us what you want to achieve and what's your problem?

Comment: replace "sid=???&" ringtonematcher.com/go/?sid=DMNMros&search=Marilyn+Manson+Spade

Comment: Please edit the question to include a clearly-differentiated "before" and "after" example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your problem is that you don't do anything with the result of the [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method. It does not alter anything, but returns a new string. If you'd want to change the `href` attributes, you will need to reassign it:

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i=0; i<links.length; i++) {
    var lnk = link[i].href;
    var newlnk = lnk.replace(/^http:\/\/www\.ringtonematcher\.com\/go\/\?sid=(\w+)&/g, 'test$1');
    link[i].href = newlnk;
}
```

I also fixed some flaws in your regex:

- It needs to be a [regex literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions), not a string (remove the apostrophes)
- You don't need to escape the `:`, `=` or `&` characters
- You don't need to wrap the character class shortcut `\w` in a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)
- <s>You don't want the `\w+` to be [greedy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)</s>

Comment: I can see no good reason why `\w+` would need to be non-greedy (and thus less compatible) here. `&` is not a word character. ISTM you are assuming too much.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes around the "regex pattern" and assign to variable

```
var regexed = lnk.replace(/^http\:\/\/www\.ringtonematcher\.com\/go\/\?sid\=([\w]+)\&/g, 'test');
```